# Ensure that a service is bound

Tags: android, android-service

Like many before me, I'm writting a chat application using asmack and Openfire.
It's still pretty basic but I've managed to send and receive messages with a user Loged In with Spark and another at the emulator.

After some SO reading I decided to create a service for my XMPP connection that I bind to every Activity. I currently have three activities

- MainActivity ( user logIn and connection to XMPPconnection).
- RosterActivity ( a listview containing the users contacts )
- ChatActivity

My question is twofold :

1. Is it necessary to bind every activity to the Service, or would it be possible to just bind MainActivity to it and pass the XMPPConnection as an extra ? If so, how can the passing be done?
2. After I log in and start the RosterActivity, I bind the service in the onCreate() method. In the onStart method, if I check the mBound variable, it's always false. I've tried SystemClock.sleep() just to see if it would work and it didn't. What really puzzles me is that when I first wrote this Activity, I used a button that, when clicked, would start the procedure to populate the list. That worked perfectly.

   So what is it that I am missing? I obviously don't want the user to have to press a button just to see the contacts, I want the list to be populated at onStart(). Why is the Service bound when I try to reach it from inside the onClickListener and why does it simply not work at onStart.

   I'm guessing it has everything to do with the binding being asynchronous, but I'm trying to find out exactly what.

MainActivity :

```
package com.example.smack_text;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
XMPPService mService;
boolean mBound = false;
Button logBtn;
Button disBtn;
EditText userTxt;
EditText passTxt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//      BIND SERVICE
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), XMPPService.class);
bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() 
{
super.onStart();

userTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userTxt);
passTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passTxt);

logBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logBtn);
disBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disBtn);
logBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
        {
        final String user = new String(userTxt.getText().toString()); 
        final String pass = new String(passTxt.getText().toString());

        if(user=="" || pass=="")
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter name and pass",           
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        if(mBound)
        {
                mService.connect(user,pass);
                Log.d("Alex","connected");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("Alex","error in connecting");
        }
        Intent roster = new Intent();
        roster.setClass(getApplicationContext(), RosterActivity.class);
        startActivity(roster);
    }
});

disBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
    {
    if(mBound)
        {
        mService.disconnect();
        Log.d("Alex","disconnected");
        }
    else
        {
        Log.d("Alex","error in disconnecting");
        }
    }
});


}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
// Unbind from the service
if (mBound) 
    {
    unbindService(mConnection);
    mBound = false;
    }
super.onDestroy();
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() 
{
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) 
    {
    mService = ((XMPPService.LocalBinder)service).getService();
    mBound = true;
    }

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) 
    {
     mBound = false;
    }
};
}
```

RosterActivity :

```
package com.example.smack_text;

import java.util.Collection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RosterActivity extends ListActivity{

boolean mBound = false;
XMPPService mService;
Button btn;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.roster);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), XMPPService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
//      btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
//      btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {

            if(mBound){
                Log.d("Alex","roster connected");

                Roster roster = mService.connection.getRoster();
//                  XWRIS TO RELOAD DN DOULEYEI
                roster.reload();

                Integer length = roster.getEntryCount();
                String[] users = new String[length];
                String[] userPresence = new String[length];

                Integer i=0;

                Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();

                for(RosterEntry entry:entries){
                    users[i] = entry.getName();


Presence tmpPres = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
                    userPresence[i] = tmpPres.toString();
                    Log.d("RosterActivity" , entry.getUser().toString());

                    i++;

                }


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>    (RosterActivity.this,

android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,     users);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);



            }
            else{

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service not bound yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
//      });
//  }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    // Unbind from the service
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {


    // Creating the dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    Object o = l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String str = o.toString();
    Log.d("Roster Activity",str);

    builder.setTitle("Start Chat?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent chat = new Intent();
            chat.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ChatActivity.class);
            startActivity(chat);
        }
    });


    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}




private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {


    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mService = ((XMPPService.LocalBinder)service).getService();

        mBound = true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
         mBound = false;

    }
    };

}
```

XMPPService:

```
package com.example.smack_text;

import java.io.File;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class XMPPService extends Service{

XMPPConnection connection;
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
    }

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        XMPPService getService() {
            return XMPPService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void connect(final String user, final String pass) {


        Log.d("Xmpp Alex","in service");


        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("10.0.2.2",5222);

//          KEYSTORE SETTINGS
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            config.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
            config.setTruststorePassword(null);
            config.setTruststorePath(null);
        } else {
            config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
            String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
            if (path == null)
                path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
                    + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
                    + "cacerts.bks";
            config.setTruststorePath(path);
        }

//          Create XMPP Connection

        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

//          THELEI TO RUNNABLE ALLIWS DN TREXEI

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    connection.connect();
                    connection.login(user, pass);
                    if(connection.isConnected()){
                        Log.d("Alex", "connected biatch!");
//                          try {
//                              Thread.sleep(5000);
//                          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                              e.printStackTrace();
//                          }
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d("Alex","not connected");
                    }


                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();


    }

    public void disconnect(){
        if(connection.isConnected()){
            connection.disconnect();
        }

else{Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not     connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

And the layouts:

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="User Name :" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/userTxt"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Password :" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userTxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/passTxt"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Log In" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/disBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/logBtn"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/userTxt"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="disconnect" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

roster.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I always think things like this can be a bit confusing, so I wrote support for making this simpler in to [Vapor API](http://vapor-api.com) - an Android framework designed to make app dev easier.

It manages all the bindings for you implicitly, and also allows you to retrieve a binding purely by the class of the Service (you needn't maintain the connection object in your code, it's done for you).

If you wanted to try it out you could do what you want like this (using [VaporActivity](http://vapor-api.com/core/activity) and [VaporServiceBindable](http://vapor-api.com/core/servicebindable)):

```
public class RosterActivity extends VaporActivity{

   public void create(VaporBundle bundle){

      $.srv(XMPPService.class); // optionally, first start the service

      // set up the callback for when the service is bound
      $.hook(SERVICE_BIND).hookIn(new $$hookee(){

          public void call(String hookName, VaporBundle args){

             // put your code here that depends on the binding...

          }

      });

      // bind to the service
      $.bind(XMPPService.class);


    }

}
```

That's obviously a simplified skeleton of the kind of problem you describe, based on the fact binding is asynchronous.

What's more, if you want to then use a method from your Service inside your Activity you can do that easily from anywhere:

```
this.service(XMPPService.class).foo(); // some method in the service
```

Under-the-hood this retrieves the earlier `ServiceConnection` that was automatically created for you, and provides you access to the `IBinder` for the service.

You should check out [VaporService](http://vapor-api.com/core/service) too if you're interested. It runs the Service inside it's own thread that you can arbitrarily pause, sleep, and restart, giving you total control over your service without worrying about the gory details.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply,it seems really usefull, but since it's my final project I need to do everything explicitly.